# SQL - multi SELECT and GROUP BY to get MIN(value) of table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, min

I am working on a price comparator website.

I have the following tables:
table item_price:

```
|| Set_id ||store_id ||currency_id ||set_price ||
||  5252  ||    1    ||     1      ||   499.99 ||
||  5252  ||    2    ||     1      ||   480    ||
||  5252  ||    3    ||     1      ||   489    ||
||  5252  ||    4    ||     2      ||   450    ||
||  5252  ||    5    ||     2      ||   445    ||
||  5252  ||    6    ||     2      ||   470    ||
||  5253  ||    1    ||     1      ||   389.99 ||
||  5253  ||    2    ||     1      ||   392    ||
||  5253  ||    3    ||     1      ||   400    ||
||  5253  ||    4    ||     2      ||   360    ||
||  5253  ||    5    ||     2      ||   370    ||
||  5253  ||    6    ||     2      ||   380    ||
```

and set_currency

```
||currency_id||currency_name||conversion_rate||
||    1      ||    EUR      ||      1        ||
||    1      ||    GBP      ||      0.9      ||
```

My goal is to get a query that brings me back the cheapest price in each currency in the following format

```
|| Set_id || store_id || Min_price_eur || Min_price_gbp_in_eur ||
||  5252  ||    5     ||      480      ||        400.5         ||
||  5253  ||    4     ||    389.99     ||        324           ||
```

---

---

so far, I only manage to do achieve half of the goal:

```
|| Set_id || store_id || Min_price_eur ||
||  5252  ||    1     ||      480      ||
||  5253  ||    1     ||      392      ||
```

using the following request:

```
SELECT 
    set_id,
    min(set_price) AS Min_price_eur,

FROM `item_price`
WHERE currency_id=1
GROUP BY set_id
```

to create the last column, i tired many things such as :

```
SELECT 
    set_id,
    min(set_price) AS Min_price_eur,
    (SELECT MIN(set_price) FROM 'item_price' WHERE currency_id=2) * (SELECT conversion_rate FROM set_currency WHERE currency_id = 2) AS  Min_price_gbp_in_eur

FROM `item_price`
WHERE currency_id=1
GROUP BY set_id
```

but i don't manage.
if anyone could offer me some help, i would really appreciate.

Thank you

ps:
here are the code to create the tables:

item price:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `item_price` (
  `set_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `set_price` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `item_price` (`set_id`, `store_id`, `currency_id`, `set_price`) VALUES
(5252, 1, 1, 499.99),
(5252, 2, 1, 480),
(5252, 3, 1, 489),
(5252, 4, 2, 450),
(5252, 5, 2, 445),
(5252, 6, 2, 470),
(5253, 1, 1, 389.55),
(5253, 2, 1, 392),
(5253, 3, 1, 400),
(5253, 4, 2, 360),
(5253, 5, 2, 370),
(5253, 6, 2, 380);


ALTER TABLE `item_price`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`set_id`,`store_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `store_id` (`store_id`),
  ADD KEY `currency_id` (`currency_id`);
COMMIT;
```

and
currency:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";



CREATE TABLE `set_currency` (
  `currency_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `currency_name` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `conversion_rate` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `set_currency` (`currency_id`, `currency_name`, `conversion_rate`) VALUES
(1, 'EUR', 1),
(2, 'GBP', 0.9);

ALTER TABLE `set_currency`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`currency_id`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: When you want the cheapest price in Pounds, do you only want to check the records where the currency actually is Pounds (`currency_id = 2`) or do you want to convert the prices in other currencies (Euros) to Pound and include them in the check as well? (Same goes when Pounds and Euros switch roles.)

Comment: @stickybit, 
When I want the cheapest price in Pounds ( Min_price_gbp_in_eur)  , I only want to check the records where the currency actually is Pounds (currency_id = 2), and brought it expressed in EUR. 

the second choice you offer me would have been  my long goal...
having the sql bringing me only the cheapest price per item accross all prices and currency

|| Set_id || store_id || Min_price_eur_accross_all_shops_and_currencies||

but, i honnestly have no idea where to start to do that in SQL.. which is not an issue as i manage it in Php from the query results. happy to learn tho!

Comment: Unclear. In desired output `store_id=1` for `Set_id=5252`. While looking source data `Min_price_eur=480` matches this correctly whereas `Min_price_gbp_in_eur=400.5` matches `store_id=5`. ???

Comment: And what version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: @Akina well spoted, i fixed it ))
Min_price_gbp_in_eur=400.5  is for store_id=5 , this correct (445*0.9)

Comment: @stickybit; Server version: 5.7.31 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Any chance to upgrade to version 8+? Window functions, which were introduced with version 8, could really help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem to me looks like aggregation with some arithmetic:

```
select ip.set_id, ip.store_id,
       min(case when currency_name = 'EUR' then ip.set_price end) as min_price_eur,
       min(case when currency_name = 'GBP' then ip.set_price / c.conversion_rate end) as min_gpbprice_eur
from item_price ip left join
     set_currency c
     on ip.currency_id = c.currency_id
group by ip.set_id, ip.store_id
```

Comment: `(ip.set_id, ip.store_id)` seems to be unique in source data (maybe `(ip.set_id, ip.store_id, currency_id)` in practice). So GROUP BY by this expression looks strange.

Comment: thank you Gordon. 
This brings me a couple of steps closer to the answer am looking for...
But, your query brings me all shop values in EUR. Not only the cheapest one, with the store_id matching it...

Comment: @Quiche . . . I thought that was what you wanted:  "My goal is to get a query that brings me back the cheapest price in each currency in the following format".  Perhaps you should ask another question more specific to your problem.

Comment: @Gordon, no, as i said, it helped me, by playing with your request i managed to get something i wanted, and also realize that i could optimize what i was seeking :) 
(reason why i "checked" your answer).

Do you know if there is a way to just bring the lowest price (out of the min_price_eur and min_price_gbp_in_eur?) in one request? 
(otherway, i am fine, i am already doing it outside of sql in php)